# custom authentication backends conflict default backend

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-authentication, django-rest-auth, custom-backend

I have 2 views in my task 
1. accepts phone number and password authentication to login user

2 . accepts phone number and token without password ,to perform that i created custom backend in which authentication done without password

when I added this custom backend in AUTHENTICTION BACKENDS in settings it make view 2 login without password auth, user login using any password!
so how to add 2 backends in settings without conflicting each other

custom backend

```py
class PasswordlessAuthBackend(ModelBackend):
    """Log in to Django without providing a password."""
    # model=UserProfile
    def authenticate(self,auth_token=None, password=None,username=None,phone_number=None,):
        try:
            return UserProfile.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return UserProfile.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

views.py:

```py
class LoginView(APIView):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer 
    authentication_classes = (ModelBackend,)
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data
                                           )
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            new_data = serializer.data
            user = serializer.validated_data
            login(request,user,backend="django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend")
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            return Response(
                            {'user':new_data,'token':token.key,},
                            status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
class TokenView(APIView):
    throttle_classes=()
    permission_classes = ()
    # authentication_classes = (PasswordlessAuthBackend,)
    serializer_class=TokenSerializer
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data,
                                           context={'request': request})
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.validated_data
            user.backend='accounts.auth_backends.PasswordlessAuthBackend'
            print(user)
            token, created = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
            login(request,user,backend='accounts.auth_backends.PasswordlessAuthBackend')
            return Response({
                    'token': token.key,
                    'user_id': user.pk,},
```

serializers.py

```py
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    email=serializers.EmailField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','country_code','phone_number','gender','birthdate','avatar','email')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = UserProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)
        return user

class LoginSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False)
    password = serializers.CharField(required=True,style={'input_type': 'password'})
    def validate(self, attrs, ):
        user = authenticate(
            phone_number=attrs['phone_number'], password=attrs['password'])
        # user = self._validate_phonenumber(phonenumber, first_token)
        if user is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('invalid credentials provided')
        return user

class TokenSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    phone_number = serializers.CharField(required=True, allow_blank=False)
    def validate(self, attrs,):
        user = authenticate(
            phone_number=attrs['phone_number'])

        if user is None:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('invalid credentials provided')
        self.instance = user
        return user
```

settings.py:

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'accounts.auth_backends.PasswordlessAuthBackend',
        "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `PasswordlessAuthBackend` logs the user in without checking the password/token.

Django inspects the parameter names for your backend to determine if it can be called. Try making a single backend for each use-case, with *only* the parameters required for that auth (e.g. phone_number, token)

```
class CustomAuthBackend:
    def authenticate(phone_number=None, token=None):
        try:
            phone = normalize_phone(phone) # standardize to single format
            return User.objects.get(phone=phone, token=token) # or whatever
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return None
```

The serializer and view can be combined in any way, but really just call authenticate.  You seem to be doing this already.

- The call to `login` is only needed if you are doing session auth
- `authenticate()` will set `user.backend` for you, which `login()` will read.  You don't need to set it manually in the call.

Comment: That's right, Custom auth wasn't True, Thanks So Much